# Why is assetsDir missing in ProcessAndroidResources?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-build-flavors

In my gradle build for an Android app, I have the following code to copy a bunch of images that are generated at build-time into the `/assets/` directory of the APK file:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
variant.mergeResources.doLast {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->  
        copy {
            from file("${project.buildDir}/" + "generated_images")
            into output.processResources.assetsDir
        }
    } 
}

def mergeAssets = tasks.getByPath("merge" + "${variant.name.capitalize()}" + "Assets")
mergeAssets.dependsOn(generateAssetImages)
```

}

Error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeVariant1Resources'.
> Could not get unknown property 'assetsDir' for task     ':app:processVariant1Resources' of
type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.
```

This **used to work perfectly**, but after upgrading from `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` to `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` , `output.processResources.assetsDir` is not defined.

What has changed? Why is assetsDir no longer a 'known property'?

Or what's a good way to get the assetsDir so that I can copy stuff into this directory? It works if I copy the generated assets into `build\intermediates\assets\{INSERT_VARIANT_NAME_HERE}\` during the build. My workaround is to derive the assetDir like so:

```
def assetsDir = output.processResources.resDir.toString().replace("res\\merged", "assets")
```

This works for now, but I'm really not happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell 25.0.0 changes from gradle-core 1.3.1 to gradle-core 2.3.0 and that appears to be a completely different system.

This is the old task: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_1.3.1/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/ProcessAndroidResources.groovy

This is the new task: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_2.3.0/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/ProcessAndroidResources.java

It seems like there was years of in parallel development and with 25.0.0 Google decided to switch over to a new branch. (At least that's my guess).

If you look at the master branch in that repo development stopped there a few years back.

Looks like we need to find a workaround to get to the asset directory. I did not find one so far.